# Jpype: ModuleNotFoundError when import classes in jar

Tags: python, jpype

### Problem

I got an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spoon'` when I set the `-Djava.class.path` as a directory `"jars/*"`.

Project structure

```
utils
├── __init__.py
├── jars
│   └── spoon-core-9.2.0-beta-4.jar
└── parse_utils.py
```

```py
# parse_utils.py

import jpype
import jpype.imports
from jpype.types import *

JARS_PATH = 'jars/*'
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),  '-Djava.class.path=' + JARS_PATH)

import spoon.Launcher as Launcher
```

### What I've tried

#### JClass and JPackage

I found a similar problem at stackoverflow [Jpype import cannot find module in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952002/jpype-import-cannot-find-module-in-jar) and I tried the top answer but failed.

```py
Launcher = jpype.JPackage('spoon').Launcher  # AttributeError: Java package 'spoon' is not valid
```

```py
Launcher = jpype.JClass('spoon.Launcher')  # TypeError: Class spoon.Launcher is not found
```

```py
Launcher = jpype.JClass("java.lang.Class").forName('spoon.Launcher') # java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spoon.Launcher
```

#### use jar path

```py
JARS_PATH = 'jars/spoon-core-9.2.0-beta-4.jar'
```

and I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ClassLoader.java", line 357, in java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
  File "Launcher.java", line 338, in sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass
  File "ClassLoader.java", line 424, in java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
  File "URLClassLoader.java", line 381, in java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.martiansoftware.jsap.JSAPException

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "org.jpype.pkg.JPypePackage.java", line -1, in org.jpype.pkg.JPypePackage.getObject
  File "Class.java", line 348, in java.lang.Class.forName
  File "Class.java", line -2, in java.lang.Class.forName0
Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/audrey/Documents/GitHub/xiaoven/codegex/utils/parse_utils.py", line 16, in <module>
    import spoon.Launcher as Launcher
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 914, in _find_spec
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/codegex/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jpype/imports.py", line 194, in find_spec
    if not hasattr(base, parts[2]):
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/martiansoftware/jsap/JSAPException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this link](https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype/issues/1002):

> I would start with checking to see if the jar was picked up in the path.
>
> ```
> import jpype
> jpype.startJVM(classpath="jars/*")
> print(jpype.java.lang.System.getProperty("java.class.path"))
> ```
>
> My guess is there is a syntax error in your test code, or the spoon jar is missing some dependency, but nothing stands out in your example. Do you have the required jar dependencies including `com.martiansoftware.jsap.JSAPException` in the jars directory?

After I download the missing jars manually according to the error log (or the `External Libraries` list under IDEA project view), it succeeded to import spoon classes.